# Checkboxes not showing in the new UI of phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Recently phpmyadmin got a revamped UI. Today I tried to create a new table and set a field as an AUTO INCREMENT id. There is a 'little' problem however, it seems impossible to do it now. I can see the 'A_I' column in the interface but can't click it or anything (as shown in the screenshot below). Same thing for the 'Null' option.

[image: Screenshot of the missing AI button]

Is it a known bug in their new UI ? I tried checking online but didn't seem to find anyone else having the same problem... How can I solve that (without having to use an sql command every time i want to create a new table) ?

Thanks

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? You appear to be using the metro theme, which version of metro are you using (at the very least, this can be seen in the phpMyAdmin folder, in `themes/metro/info.inc.php`)? Perhaps you upgraded your phpMyAdmin and didn't also download a newer version of the metro theme. As far as I know, the UI hasn't really changed since version 4.0.0 was released in 2013; which version were you running?

Comment: Also, which browser are you using?

Comment: I've tried a couple of things and can't reproduce this with the correct metro version for my phpMyAdmin version in Firefox or Chrome. Can you reproduce it on the demo server at https://demo.phpmyadmin.net ?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch I don't actually manage phpMyAdmin myself, it is completely managed by my shared hosting provider, and it recently changed. That's why I assumed it was a recent update. Seems like they just took some time to update it on their side and forgot to add the theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aaand after a few minutes of digging I finally found the culprit...

A piece of css code i found while trying to check the source out:

```
.chrome input[type="checkbox"] {
    left: -9999px;
    position: relative;
}
```

For some reason they offset all of the checkboxes 10k pixels to the left...

Am I the only one who finds this insane ? Or is there actually a smart reason for them to have done that ? (unless this is just one of these things that we, developers, sometimes forget in the code after testing)

Anyway, problem solved, just needed to remove that offset and the checkboxes are finally back where they belong:

[image: Screenshot]